# Refresh Parent CRM Page after child ASP.net page closed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

This is for CRM 2016 on premise.

I have a custom button in the command bar of CRM 2016 that uses a javaScript web resource to call an external asp.net page located on another server. This external page allows the user to perform some custom actions that are then displayed on one of the subgrids of the parent page.

Here is the javascript that the CRM button uses to open the external page.

```
function openPricingForm() {

var loc = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
var pl = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('pricelevelid').getValue();
var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var type = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();

var url = 'http://app.domain.com/customPage.aspx?pl='+ pl[0].id +'&id='+ id + '&type=' + type + '&loc=' + loc;

var title = 'Select Products';
var w = 500;
var h = 600;
var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
top = top - (top * 0.25);
var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

// Puts focus on the newWindow
if (window.focus) {
    newWindow.focus();
    }
}
```

I need to be able to refresh the parent CRM page to display the changes that were made by the asp.net page. I would prefer to just refresh the subgrid on the parent page but if I have to I would be fine with just reloading the entire page.

I have tried using a javascript function on the child page to call window.opener.location.reload() on the window unload event but it is not working on the parent CRM page. I have also tried window.opener.parent.refreshParent(). I think the problem is that window.opener does not contain a value because the external page is not being opened by the CRM page, it is opened by the javascript function.

Is there some way to pass this value through the javascript so that I have a value in window.opener to work with?

Is there a way to a identify the subgrid on the parent page and post a refresh command to it?

Perhaps there's an even better solution that I'm missing? I'm open to any suggestions on a way to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if window.postMessage works for windows, but you could investigate.

Another option would be to, instead of loading the child page in a new window, loading it in an iframe overlay.  Then you'd definitely be able to use postMessage and the UX would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will take a look at window.postMessage and see it that could be useful. I did try creating an html wrapper to iframe my child page but it broke the AJAX update panels on the form. I have a dropdown list that then populates a listbox base on the selection  and then a 2nd listbox that shows selections from the previous listbox.